# Does higher [OH] not entail higher pH?

Tags: acid-base, ph

> A student has equal volumes of $\pu{1.0 mol dm-3}$ sodium hydroxide and ammonia solutions. Which statement about the solutions is correct?
>
> A. Sodium hydroxide has a lower electrical conductivity than ammonia.
> B. Sodium hydroxide has a higher hydrogen ion concentration than ammonia.
> C. Sodium hydroxide has a higher pH than ammonia.
> D. Sodium hydroxide has a higher hydroxide ion concentration than ammonia.

The answer is C, and I understand why. What I do not understand is why D isn't correct also? Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Share some reasoning why C is true and why you think D should be true.

Comment: At first glance I'm inclined to agree with you. Where is this question from?

Comment: D is also correct but as you know sodium hydroxide is strong base and ammonia solution is a weak base. In weak base solution we must know Kb to calculate hydroxide ion concentration. Although a solution of weak base has lower concentration of hydroxide ion compared to a solution of a strong base having same concentration.

Answer (score 1):

See this website. Essentially it's a misprint in the IB Chem testbank.

https://www.thinkib.net/chemistry/blog/8944/multiple-choice-answers

There's a correct rewording for D that makes C the only correct answer, according to the link I just posted.